# iPhone keyboard with a UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, keyboard, uitextview

I feel that this question has been asked 10^78 times, but for some reason, am unable to find the question, nor the answer ..

I want to add a keyboard with a uitextView at the top .. Exactly like the default SMS application on the iPhone ..

How can I do that?

*Bonus: if you can also give me a hint as to how to animate it with the keyboard (goes down when the keyboard animates out .. and goes up with the keyboard);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `UIToolbar` (containing your text views, etc.) and set the `inputAccessoryView` property of the `UITextView` to that toolbar. The animation should take place without any additional code.

See http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/adding-a-toolbar-with-next-previous-above-uitextfield-keyboard-iphone/

Comment: Great! .. what about the rounded UITextView ?? I couldn't find it in the UITextView properties in interface builder ..?
Exactly like the SMS app?

Comment: You can round the corners using `myTextView.layer.cornerRadius`. See the documentation on `CALayer`.

Comment: hmm .. This isn't a private API, right? I don't see it documented in the API reference ...

Comment: No. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/cornerRadius

Comment: "Even though it's not documented in the UITextView API reference, it's still the the CALayer documentation" .. is whaat you're gonna say, right? I just realized that (doh!).